# How to add an outerglow to a line

Tags: d3.js, svg, colormatrix

I have a line graph like the below:

```
var lines = svg.selectAll(".lines")
      .data(data_array)
      .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class','lines');

    lines
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      //.style('stroke', function(d) { var length = d.values.length - 1; return color(d.values[length].poll); })
      .style('fill','none')
      .style('stroke','#dc545e')
      .style("stroke-width", 3);
```

It's fine.

But I want to add an outerglow to each graph so that they don't overlap.

Here's one way:

```
var defs = svg.append("defs");

var filter = defs.append("filter")
.attr("id", "drop-shadow")
.attr("height", "130%");

// SourceAlpha refers to opacity of graphic that this filter will be applied to
// convolve that with a Gaussian with standard deviation 3 and store result
// in blur

var colormatrix = "0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1";
filter.append("feColorMatrix")
    .attr('type','matrix')
    //.attr("values", colormatrix);

filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("stdDeviation", 2)
    .attr("result", "coloredBlur");

// translate output of Gaussian blur to the right and downwards with 2px
// store result in offsetBlur

// overlay original SourceGraphic over translated blurred opacity by using
// feMerge filter. Order of specifying inputs is important!
var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "coloredBlur")
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");
```

But this just doesn't add the colors I want.

I want it to be white. But I'm having no luck in figuring out the color matrix.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be white, then your color matrix should be:

"0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 1 0"